# Android Virtual Device

Tags: applications

I want to run my first App 'Hello World' and want to create AVD, so I could run it using emulator . I am using android studio. When I create AVD with the given below configurations and launch emulator, i receive following error message;

" Starting emulator for AVD 'test'emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed! "

I am using following AVD settings:

Device = Nexus 6(5.96", 1440 x 2560:560dpi)
Targt = Android 5.0.1 - API Level 21
CPU/ABI = Intel Atom (x86)

My computer configurations are as;

Accer Aspire 5732Z
Intel Pentium Processor T4300 (2.1GHz)
Memory 4GB

I would appreciate someones help.

Regards
UJB

Comment: "HAX kernel module is not installed!". Please first read the error and search for it (Google). Solutions can be found more than enough.

Comment: Genymotion is also a nice alternative ;)

Comment: I have tried genymotion as well, when I try to launch it, error says "Unable to load virtual box engine".

Answer (score 0):

Your processor doesn't include support for Intel VT-x (virtualization technology), which is required by Intel HAXM. This means you can't run a x86-based device on your PC. You'll have to use the ARM CPU images instead.